# Should the [mass] tag be burninated?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

The [mass](/questions/tagged/mass) tag doesn't have a wiki summary and there are 69 questions with the tag as of now.  Most of these seem to pertain to:

- mass email
- mass replace
- mass update
- mass delete
- mass data
- mass action
- mass payment
- mass migration
- mass add
- mass notification
- mass rename
- mass storage

Could we burninate [mass](/questions/tagged/mass), please?  (A `mass` edit ...)

Comment: What a pain in the `mass`.  Watch out for those physics questions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree. I've manually removed this tag from the 69 questions that used the tag. So this tag will be removed within 24 hours.

Comment: The world is _perfect_ without __mass__.  Great!